# Is there an online service that will help me regulate my incoming webhook rate?

Tags: php

I have connected a mail delivery platform to a CRM system with a custom PHP application i built. So now webhooks will get sent from one platform to the other. The payloads are different types of events. For instance we have "email send" event, "email opened" event, "link within email clicked" event, "email bounced" event and so on.

Now when a bulk email campaign is sent we send to about 20k contacts or something, maybe more don't know, now lots of people open their emails instantly so we get tonnes of "email opened" events all at once. This overloads the server associated with the PHP integration application I created.

So I'm sure other integration developers have experienced such problems before. One obvious solution I can think of, that others might have also considered, is using some sort of an incoming webhook rate regulation service that can neatly put all the webhooks into a queue and relay them to you based on a rate that you prefer.

I haven't tried it yet but **rudderstack** is a service that might offer such a feature but I still need to test to see if it does.

Anyway, I know webhook integration is still quite cutting edge and the industry is still mostly dominated by **zapier** etc. I'm sure custom integration developers like me are popping up here and there, and I hope someone here is such a person and is wiser than I am.

If you are such a person - do you know - is there an online service that will help me regulate my incoming webhook rate?

Answer (score 0):

It seems https://hookdeck.com seems to claim to do this. As they claim in this article https://hookdeck.com/blog/post/how-we-built-a-rate-limiter-for-

"
We built Hookdeck with one goal in mind: free developers from the burden of assembling their own webhook infrastructure by providing a reliable, ready-made alternative. If we were going to accomplish this task, the first step would be to build a robust queueing system that would allow our users to process webhooks asynchronously at a predetermined rate.
"

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).